# Not able to deploy node js app on heroku properly

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, video-streaming, production-environment

I had made a video-call app which is running well on my local pc, but when I pushed all files to heroku, I am not able to see other person's video.

Here is my script.js(front-end client side file):

```
//declaring socket constant
const socket = io("/");


//identifying video grid element
const videoGridElement = document.getElementById("video-grid");
//creating new element
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;

//peerjs variable declaring here
const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host:host,
  port:port,
  path: '/a'
})

//getting media of user
var getUserMedia =
  navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

  peer.on("open", function(id){
    socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
  });

let myVideoStream;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video:true,
  audio:true
}).then(function(stream){
    myVideoStream = stream;

    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)


    peer.on("call", function(call){
      call.answer(stream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");

      call.on("stream", function(userVideoStream){
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      })
    });

      socket.on("user-connected", function(userId){
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
      });



})




peer.on("call", function(call){
  getUserMedia({
      video:true,
      audio:true

  }, function(stream){
    call.answer(stream);
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    call.on("stream", function (remoteStream) {
      addVideoStream(video, remoteStream);
    });
  }, function(err){
      console.log(err);
  })
})



const addVideoStream = function(videoElement, stream){
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  videoElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    videoElement.play();
  });
  videoGridElement.append(videoElement);


  let totalUsers = document.getElementsByTagName("video").length;
  if (totalUsers > 1) {
    for (let index = 0; index < totalUsers; index++) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("video")[index].style.width =
        100 / totalUsers + "%";
    }
  }
}


const connectToNewUser = function(userId, stream){
  var call = peer.call(userId, stream)

  var video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", function(userVideoStream){
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
  })
}
```

Here is the server.js file(server side file):

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//making server constant
const server = require("http").Server(app);

//requirinng uuid package
const { v4 : uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

//declaring io constant
const io = require("socket.io")(server);


//using peer server
const {ExpressPeerServer} = require("peer");
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
  debug: true
})

//setting view engine to ejs and express to use static files
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

//
app.use("/a", peerServer);


//when user gets on the home route, it redirects him to new room
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  const id = uuidv4();
  res.redirect("/"+ id);
})

//listening on port 3030
const port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
server.listen(port);

//using routing parametes of express, to pass different room files to
//different rooms
app.get("/:room", function(req,res){
  console.log(req.hostname);
  res.render("room", {roomId:req.params.room, myPort:port, myHost: req.hostname});
})



//on connection of any new user
io.on("connection", function(socket){
  //when joinroom is emmited from frontend along with roomid and,
  //userId, this code inside it will be executed
  socket.on("join-room", function(roomId, userId){
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);


  })
})
```

And here is the room.ejs file in the room directory:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Room</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/1.3.1/peerjs.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>";
      const port = "<%= myPort %>";
      const host = "<%= myHost %>";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi there!</h1>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main__left">
        <div class="main__videos">
          <div id="video-grid">
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
      </div>

    <script src="/script.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "zoom-clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "peer": "^0.5.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

I am not able to determine whether I have made correct changes required for deploying or not. Please help me identify if I am missing some code piece here.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined a Procfile in the root of your project?

Comment: Yes I had added it.
"web: node server.js" this is the code in the procfile.